# Detect page change in dash

Tags: javascript, python, plotly-dash

I am developing a `dash` web application which is a `multi` page app. Below is my structure

```
- project/
  - pages/
     - home.py
     - contact.py
     - graph.py
  - app.py
  - index.py
```

In `app.py`, I have a component `dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=True),` to load different pages to a `html.Div(id="page-content")` using a callback. The pages are getting loaded successfully as user click on sidebar having `navlinks` for each page.

Say I am on `home` page (localhost/home) and I now click to go to `contact` page (localhost/contact), It works. Here, before leaving the `home` page, I am want to save the data in `dcc.store` component. One way is to have `hidden` button and activate this button callback through javascript. For that, In `assets` folder I have created a `custom-script.js`

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', e=>{
    if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
        console.log("user is focused on the page")
   } else {
    // code to trigger button click event to activate callback
    console.log("user left the page")
   }  
});
```

But what I am noticing is that even though I am switching from `home` page to `contact` page **the event is not firing**. May be an update of the page content by callback does not seems to affect refresh( even setting as True). But If, I do hard refresh via browser refresh button on `home` page **the event is fired**

Is there a any other way to detect page change using dash or javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need a dash callback *and* the custom script :

- If navigating to a page within your app via one of the `Location` links doesn't trigger the `visibilitychange` event, you can still update the store using a dash callback (defined in app.py, as well as the Location and Store components), eg.

  ```py
  @app.callback(
      Output("store-id", "data"),
      Input('url', 'pathname'),
      State("store-id", "data"),
      prevent_initial_call=True,
  )
  def update_store(pathname, data):
      data['someproperty'] = 'some value'
      return data
  ```
- And for the cases when user browser-refreshes the page or goes to another website, the `visibilitychange` event should fire properly. However, triggering a button click from the event handler is not the best choice I think because the script will probably terminate before the button-click callback resolves (user leaves the page), instead you could directly load and update the storage in the visibilitychange handler, eg.

  ```js
  document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', e => {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
      console.log("user is focused on the page");
    } 
    else {
      // Update store data
      const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('store-id'));
      data.someproperty = 'some value';
      localStorage.setItem('store-id', JSON.stringify(data ));

      console.log("user left the page");
    }
  });
  ```

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks. For multi page app, It seems to define `dcc.store` on the `app.py` Instead of on a particular page.